# Can a column be created in a view in MySQL if It does not exist in any table and it's value is calculated If certain condition is true

Tags: mysql, if-statement, join, view

Here is what I am trying to do. I have One table that looks like this:

```
+--------+------------+-----------+------------+
| UserID | ContractID | StartDate |  EndDate   |
+--------+------------+-----------+------------+
|      1 |        211 | 5/31/2016 | 8/27/2016  |
|      1 |         14 | 7/13/2016 | 9/10/2016  |
|      1 |        277 | 8/6/2016  | 10/15/2016 |
+--------+------------+-----------+------------+
```

And I have a second Table that looks like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+
| UserID |      Status       | StatusDate |
+--------+-------------------+------------+
|      1 | Applicant         | 5/20/2016  |
|      1 | Interviewing      | 5/21/2016  |
|      1 | Submitted Profile | 6/5/2016   |
|      1 | Accepted          | 8/1/2016   |
+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

And I am trying to create a view That uses both these tables and produces something like this:

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| UserID |      Status       | StatusDate | ContractID | StartDate  |  EndDate   |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|      1 | Applicant         | 5/20/2016  | blank      | blank      | blank      |
|      1 | Interviewing      | 5/21/2016  | 211*       | 5/31/2016  | 8/27/2016  |
|      1 | Submitted Profile | 6/5/2016   | 14**       | 7/13/2016  | 9/10/2016  |
|      1 | Accepted          | 8/1/2016   | 277***     | 9/15/2016  | 10/15/2016 |
|      1 | Accepted          | 8/1/2016   | 400****    | 10/20/2016 | 10/25/2016 |
+--------+-------------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

* because `StartDate` is after the applicant is interviewed
** because `StartDate` is after the profile is submitted
*** because `StartDate` is in after the profile is accepted
**** because `StartDate` is in after the profile is accepted

Basically I want to do a join based of a condition. Does it look possible?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Here we help you fix YOUR CODE, we do not wtire it for you.

Comment: SELECT, LEFT JOIN, LEFT JOIN, IF, AS, I think in that order.

Comment: @Kontsnor Thanks Man, Got the query in place, Had to create 2 views for the first two tables as they were derived from other tables. The sequence is SELECT, LEFT JOIN, IF , AS. I will post the query soon, need some time as it is the demo data that I posted above.